# Generic Binary Tree Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

my Task ist to write a generic binary tree in java with classes Node and Tree and NodeActionInterface

```
public interface NodeActionInterface {
public void action(); }
```

This is my Node:

```
public class Node <T> implements NodeActionInterface {

<T> data;
Node leftTree;
Node rightTree;

public <T> Node(<T> data){
   this.data = data;
}
 @Override
    public void action() {

    }
```

But there are errors like "Identifier expected" and some others.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Could you share the actual errors (e.g. including line numbers), rather than what the errors are "like"?

Comment: `<T> data` -> `T data`.

Comment: In the line "<T> data;" there are the errors: Identifier expected, Unexpected token, Cannot resolve symbol "data"

Comment: @saka1029, Thank you, i corrected it! Now there's still an error in line this.data = data : Incompatible types: Required T, Found T

Comment: Please read [mcve]. And then **understand**: SO is not a free tutor service where people spend their time guiding you through all the syntax errors you encounter. Dumping code, and then asking people to fix one problem after the next is **not** appreciated. My hint: dont write 50 lines of code to **then** run the compiler. Only write a few lines of code (just enough so that you have something meaningful that you think "this should compile"). Then run the compiler. fix problems. write 5 lines again. and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can i compare them now? So in the class "Binary Tree" if i want to add a new Node, i should compare it to "root". If i write something like: (if a < b) it works only for Integers, and Doubles. But how can i compare it if T is a String or any other type ?

Comment: @Antoshka you need to bound `T`: `Node<T extends Comparable<T>>`. Then you can compare elements using, e.g. `leftTree.data.compareTo(rightTree.data)`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are quite a number of syntax errors:

```
public class Node <T> implements NodeActionInterface
{
    // <T> data;
    T data;
//  ^ T is the data type...

    Node<T> leftTree;
    Node<T> rightTree;
//      ^  not really an errror, but you should use the generic here

    //public <T> Node(<T> data)
    public Node(T data)
//        ^ declared another T hiding the "outer" T
//              ^ again: data type is T
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: "constructors do not have return types" `public <T> Node(T data)` isn't declaring a return type, it's declaring a type variable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. All I'm saying is that [there is nothing wrong with declaring a type variable on a constructor](http://ideone.com/6ECSIG). You *shouldn't* in this code (at least, not if you call it `T`), because it hides the class-level `T`, so you wouldn't be able to assign `this.data = data`; it's just that the reason you are giving for it not being there is not correct.

Comment: @AndyTurner OK, seems as if I've been out too long of Java, haven't seen this construct before. Works fine, if we have `<TT>` instead. Can you provide me any references to so that I fix my answer appropriately?

Comment: Your answer looks fine now; but you can see about type variables on constructors in the language spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. Really interesting -- and I must have really been out of Java for a while now...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are providing not much info about it. May try this will get a clue.This is syntax corrected given code.

```
public class Node <T> implements NodeActionInterface  {

T data;
Node leftTree;
Node rightTree;

public T Node(T data){        
    this.data = data;
    return data;
}
```